# how to control speed of react-flip-numbers in react

Tags: reactjs, animation, css-animations, animatewithduration

I have used react-flip-numbers package for count-up animation. I want to animate numbers from top to bottom or bottom to top using react-flip-numbers package.. but it's not working smoothly and in average speed.

I want smooth animation with average speed

Comment: try using ```delay``` prop

Comment: I already tried this

<FlipNumbers
     height={80}
     width={50}
     color='#181818'
     background='#f9f8fa'
     numberClassName='state--counter'
     play
     perspective={300}
     duration={5}
     delay={0.2} // Duration of the animation in seconds
     numbers={countVal.toString() as string}
    />

Comment: @HritikSharma Please do not code-format things that are not code.